# Nodejs Cheerio DOM parser: Is there a way to select a specific range of elements?

Tags: node.js, dom, cheerio

I want to select a specific range of elements, via a Cheerio selector. For example, something like:

$('.someClass [0-3]')

Before resorting to just slicing it with JS, i'd like to explore the option of doing it using the selector itself(i'm not even sure it's possible with Jquery).

Can it be done?

Comment: That's more "How do I say 'the first four elements' in a CSS query?", but even then: why do you want to do it in the selector? It's not like slicing is a slow operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheerio uses CSS selectors, like JQuery so something like this should work.

`$('.someclass:nth-child(-n+3)')`

Comment: As Pomax noted, I missed that comment unfortunately.